# Render checkbox in a table row on click of button with #ajax property

Tags: ajax

I have a form element in `hook_form` as below,

```
$form['check'] = array('#type' => 'checkbox',);
```

and also an add button, on the click of which a table renders, with a checkbox in every row each time the button is clicked. This is how its rendered in ajax callback function,

```
$header = array(t('checkbox'));
$rows[] = array(drupal_render($form['check']));
```

My question is in the submit function of the form, when I print the `form_state` values of the form, I am getting the value of the checkbox as 0 even if it is checked.

Kindly reply. I am trying this from many days.